# How to configure TinyMCE to allow block-level elements inside inline element?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have an HTML where inline element **span** which hold block element example **div**. I have pasted below HTML source in the source view of TinyMCE and press Ok

```
<span>plain text<div>test div</div></span>​
```

Further, I have click on the source view and HTML it changes to the below HTML where span automatically gets closed and new span added to the HTML,

```
<p><span><span>plain text</span></span></p>
<div>test div</div>
<p>​</p>
```

I know, we can't have block element inside the inline element(i.e. HTML global rule), but I am not in position to make changes in the current system.

Update: I have tried to solution mention here but not worked well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14603631/4420468

Comment: hmm, is exchanging tags after inserting the content in tinymce an option?

Comment: @Thariama Yes, till the content inserted in the TinyMCE, it's proper but when we click on the source button after content insert, that tags gets exchanged.

Answer (score 0):

There is a config option to control this behavior.

> #### valid_children
>
> The valid_children enables you to control what child elements can exists within specified parent elements.

[see docs for further information](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-docs/blob/master/_includes/configuration/valid-children.md)